# Where can i find a comma separated list of countries in swedish?

Tags: forms, list, csv, countries

I am currently building a web app which includes a form with a drop down menu with a list of all the world's countries in Swedish. I know that these libraries exist but the thing is that I need to populate the list using SQL. I have found comma separated lists in English, but then what remains is to translate them, which of course is very time consuming.

Does any one know a smart way of extracting this data from a library of countries and then formatting it in a simple manner? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, finally I just copied source-code from a site with drop down and stripped it of all the html tags. Here is a list of all the world's countries in Swedish (in a comma separated list). Hope this helps some one.

```
'Afghanistan','Albanien','Algeriet','Angola','Antigua och Barbuda','Argentina','Australien','Azerbajdzjan','Österrike','Östtimor','Bahamas','Bahrain','Bangladesh','Barbados','Belgien','Benin','Bermuda','Bhutan','Bolivia','Bosnien och Hercegovina','Botswana','Brasilien','Brunei Darussalam','Bulgarien','Burkina Faso','Burundi','Centralafrikanska Republiken','Chile','Colombia','Costa Rica','Cypern','Danmark','Demokratiska Republiken Kongo','Dominikanska Republiken','Ecuador','Egypten','El Salvador','Elfenbenskusten','Estland','Etiopien','Färöarna','Förenade Arabemiraten','Filippinerna','Finland','Frankrike','Gabon','Georgien','Ghana','Gibraltar','Grönland','Grekland','Grenada','Guatemala','Honduras','Hong Kong','Indien','Indonesien','Irak','Iran','Irland','Island','Israel','Italien','Jamaica','Japan','Jemen','Jersey','Jordanien','Kambodja','Kanada','Kazakstan','Kenya','Kina','Kiribati','Kroatien','Kuba','Kuwait','Laos','Lettland','Libanon','Libyen','Litauen','Luxemburg','Madagaskar','Makedonien','Malawi','Malaysia','Maldiverna','Mali','Malta','Marocko','Mauritius','Mexiko','Mocambique','Monaco','Mongoliet','Myanmar','Namibia','Nederländerna','Nederländska Antillerna','Nepal','Nicaragua','Niger','Nigeria','Norge','Nya Zeeland','Oman','Pakistan','Panama','Paraguay','Peru','Polen','Portugal','Puerto Rico','Qatar','Rumänien','Rwanda','Ryssland','Saint Lucia','Saint Vincent och Grenadinerna','Samoa','San Marino','Sao Tome och Principe','Saudiarabien','Schweiz','Senegal','Serbien och Montenegro','Seychellerna','Sierra Leone','Singapore','Slovakien','Slovenien','Somalia','Spanien','Sri Lanka','Sudan','Surinam','Sverige','Swaziland','Sydafrika','Sydkorea','Syrien','Taiwan','Tanzania','Thailand','Tjeckien','Trinidad och Tobago','Tunisien','Turkiet','Tyskland','Uganda','Ukraina','Ungern','Uruguay','USA','Uzbekistan','Venezuela','Vietnam','Vitryssland','Zambia','Zimbabwe'
```